# JavaScript image rotator time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-rotation

I have a following code for rotating images on webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.pics').cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                next:    '#next',
                prev:    '#prev' 
            });
        });
</script>
```

How can i add an option for time delay on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.pics').cycle({
                fx:      'fade',
                next:    '#next',
                prev:    '#prev',
                speed:   300, 
                timeout: 2000
            });


        });
</script>
```